# Need to customize devise sign-up flow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

My signup works like this:

1. User takes a quiz, which is submitted as a form and stored in the session
2. User registers for the site using either Facebook or a classic username/password
3. Upon successful registration, the quiz results are persisted with the user

I thought of making my signup start with a separate controller action in step #1, persisting the results to session, then creating a post-registration callback for devise to save the results in step #3.

What's the best approach to implement this? Will the session be overwritten in step #2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You approach is correct.

You should store the quiz result in a specific session hash, like in `session[:quiz]` that won't be overriden when the user sucessfully login using devise registration.

Then you may override the devise registration controller and add the quiz result in the User with the other information

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    super
    #find user and set the quiz to persist
  end

end
```